# TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer image-watermark node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, watermark

I am trying to add watermark on my image, but when i embed the watermark and give it the image that i have in my request it always gives me this error

```
TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
```

This is my sample node.js code

```
const watermark = require('image-watermark');

file = req.file('file');

const options = {
    text: 'sample watermark',
    dstPath: './images',
};

watermark.embedWatermark(file, options, (error) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('Succefully embeded watermark');
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems like your `req,file` is not a string or Buffer. Try `console.log(typeof file)` to identify the data type, and post the results

Comment: it is giving me an object, i am sending the image here in FormData().

Comment: Try saving your file, and then passing the path instead of passing the file object